# PHP statements in HTML (difference)

Tags: php, html

Basically I was just wondering what is the difference between this two statements in HTML script:

```
<?php if($something == null) { ?>
  <div>This is just HTML code</div>
<?php } ?>
```

and:

```
<?php if($something == null) {
  echo '<div>This is just HTML code passed from PHP</div>';
} ?>
```

Is there a preferred way?

Comment: I think both are correct

Comment: I think both are terrible, because you're mixing front- and backend. There should be a clear and clean seperation. Perhaps you may investigate into a PHP template engine, i.e. [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: Nope no preferred objective way, Use either of them you like. Its as subjective as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must try to write it as clean as possible. And preferred one is the neater one. Now what about this:

```
<?PHP if($something == null): ?>
    <div>This is just HTML code</div>
<?PHP endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, and thank you for answering about CodeIgniter. I apologize for deleting my comment but I still happened to see yours. I up voted you so that you were at least at 0.

Comment: You're welcome dude :). To prevent down voting please search first. It has  bad effect ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no difference. But there's a third, better syntax that PHP provides for templating:

```
<?php if($something == null): ?>
  <div>This is just HTML code</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

This way you can avoid stray `}` brace errors since this is easier to read. `for` and `foreach` also support this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Both code blocks work similarly.

There is **NO** difference in the output.

However, the 1st method is preferred as it omits the unnecessary string handling which becomes tedious in situations where `"` and `'` are used in the `HTML` code.

It also keeps the `HTML` and `PHP` code separate which makes it easier to maintain.

The following code should be preferred.

```
<?php if($something == null) { ?>
  <div>This is just HTML code</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both gives the same output, however,

This is the not the preferred and unclear type of code: 
    `<?php if($something == null) { ?>
     <div>This is just HTML code</div>
    <?php } ?>`

whereas,the second code is simple to read and understand and usually used when you have to print some dynamic php content in between html code.